# angular filter does not filter elements out

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, ecmascript-6

I am using a filter function to filter objects out of an array. 
**Problem**: The elements stay in the array, even if they should not! Why are these objects kept in the array although I am using the filter?

```
async filterPspDeliveries(pspDeliveryList: PspDelivery[]){
    try {
        return pspDeliveryList.filter(pspDelivery => pspDelivery.packageList.length > 0);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
}
```

the filter is used in the same class here:

```
for (let psp of pspList){
    let tmpDeliveryList = await this.filterPspDeliveries(psp.deliveryList);
    psp.deliveryList = tmpDeliveryList;
}
```

**Note**: I simply want to filter out deliveries that do not contain a package list.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Try removing the try-catch to see if any errors are thrown.

Comment: why my answer is downvoted? if it's not working you should mention it,

Answer (score 0):

Try catch does not have meaning here as `.filter` function will always be successful. Try replacing with the following!:

```
function filterPspDeliveries(pspDeliveryList: PspDelivery[]) {
    return pspDeliveryList.filter(pspDelivery => pspDelivery.packageList && pspDelivery.packageList.length > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) :

> The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. It can only be used
>   inside an async function.

The problem is that you're awaiting for a function that do not return a Promise. Instead, your function `async filterPspDeliveries` is returning an array of PspDelivery.

Also, you don't need `async` keyword on `filterPspDeliveries` method since you're not awaiting anything.

The solution would be either:

#### Solution 1

Remove the `await` keywork keyword:

```
 for(let psp of pspList){
      let tmpDeliveryList =  this.filterPspDeliveries(psp.deliveryList);
      psp.deliveryList = tmpDeliveryList;
    }
```

#### Solution 2

Keep the `await` keyword but returning a promise in `filterPspDeliveries`:

```
  filterPspDeliveries(pspDeliveryList: PspDelivery[]): Promise<PspDelivery[]> {
    try {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        let result = pspDeliveryList.filter((pspDelivery) => {
          return (pspDelivery.packageList.length > 0);
        })
        resolve(result);
        return;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }


for(let psp of pspList){
      let tmpDeliveryList = await this.filterPspDeliveries(psp.deliveryList);
      psp.deliveryList = tmpDeliveryList;
    }
```

You can check it working with both solutions [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-sync-async-filtering).

Answer (score -2):

What about changing to this:

```
async filterPspDeliveries(pspDeliveryList: PspDelivery[]){
    try{
      return pspDeliveryList.filter((pspDelivery) => pspDelivery.packageList && pspDelivery.packageList.length > 0);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```